# Why strtok isn't working?

Tags: c, arrays, string, substring, strtok

The code is pretty simple. I don't understand why my program crashes when I try to print out `pointok2`. Maybe I don't see the problem because I am tired or something. A little help would be appreciated.

`Tokmain` will always be of the format "word word".

```
scanf("%s",&tokmain);
for(i=0;i<50;i++) {
    if (tokmain[i]=='\n') {
        tokmain[i]='\0';
        lettercount=i;
        break;
    }
}
pointok1=strtok(tokmain,delim);
pointok2=strtok(NULL,delim);

puts(pointok1);
puts(pointok2);`
```

Comment: What is the value of `delim`?

Comment: Agree with ^, what the delimiter is could very well be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` truncates at the space. So, `tokmain` will only have "word" when you enter "word word".

Try

```
scanf("%49[^\n]s",&tokmain); /*Notice the format string*/

for(i=0;i<50;i++) {
    if (tokmain[i]=='\n') {
        tokmain[i]='\0';
        lettercount=i;
        break;
    }
}
pointok1=strtok(tokmain,delim);
pointok2=strtok(NULL,delim);

puts(pointok1);
puts(pointok2);`
```

Comment: It might be easier to use `"%49[^\n]"`.  Good job on using the length-limited format string. It would also be more reassuring if you tested the return value from `scanf()` to ensure it got some data. Finally, since `strtok()` can return `NULL` if it doesn't like what it gets, it is probably sensible to test `pointok1` and `pointok2` for nullness before trying to print them via `puts()`, which objects to null pointers (that is, you invoke undefined behaviour if you pass a null pointer to `puts()` and anything could happen, including a crash).

Comment: thanks for answering what i posted, but i had this changed the momment i posted this.I changed the scanf with an fgets and fgets doesnt seem to work at all.The delim is a space as you figured it out.I also wrote a check as you suggested for NULL even though i will always have an input.Do you might know whats causing fgets to not work ? fgets(tokmain,50,stdin) that was what i was meant to post in the start and replacing the newline fgets drags with it.

Comment: Yea i figured it out.It was a leftover character that was getting in the way because this is in a switch case.Used a getchar();. Everything works as it should.Thanks again for your time.